# Access Microsoft APIs using Azure AD-App (OAuth2)

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

I'm trying to use Azure AD application (using oauth2) to access another tenants Microsoft API data (graph API, storage API , etc...)

My question is, is it possible to use an app created in global cloud to authorize and fetch dat from a tenant who is in another national cloud (USGov/Germany/China) ?

I was able to successfully fetch another tenant data by setting the app to "multi tenant"

As a summary I want to create an app in global national cloud and ask a user from a tenant in another national cloud to authorize my app, and then fetch data given he/she authorized my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible.

The data from different cloud (Azure cloud and national cloud) are not interoperable. The national cloud are managed by specific country(The customer data stays in that country). Microsoft only provides technical support.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Tony Ju
hope this should be right... 
I got same sort of reply in Microsoft Forum too
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/63b1c36b-c6c7-4c32-8ddb-2d831e926f67/access-microsoft-apis-using-azure-adapp-oauth2?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview